# Table spacing in latex

Tags: tables, spacing, tabu

I struggle with constructing tables in LaTeX. As you can see in my attached table, the placement of the header as well as the placement of the text within the left cells is incorrect. I would like to achieve a centered header in the first row (centered between "run" and "warten") and a break in "Agent i vom Typ 2", such that the text doesn't cross the next column "warten".  [image]
The corresponding code is given by:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}                              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu, float, multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H] \centering \tabulinesep=1.2mm $\begin{tabu}{ r|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{3}{ c }{\text{Typ 2-Agent $\neq i$}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{Run}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\text{Warten}} \\
\cline{2-3}   \multirow{2}{*}{Agent $i$ vom Typ 2}
\text{Run} & \begin{cases} r_{1} & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit} \frac{1}{fr_{1}} \\
0 & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit } 1-\frac{1}{fr_{1}} 
\end{cases} & r_{1} \\
\cline{2-3}
\text{Warten} & 0 & \dfrac{(1-fr_{1})\tilde{R}}{1-f} \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabu}$\caption{Auszahlungsmatrix im "`Post-Deposit Game"'} \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Maybe one of you may help me by fixing this issue. If there has been already a question, which resembles my problem, I would be gratuful, if you apprise me with the corresponding link.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was playing arround with the first part of your problem... Your source of the problen is the deferent lengths of the last two columns... using multicolumn and center, it centers in the middle of these two columns (and this is very close to the first of these)... I suppose you need a method of calculation of the length (like savebox or something) of the last two columns and an appropriate hspace... upvoted your question... Seems interesting

Comment: Also you use for columns defining your tabular and using only 3 in its first line which is a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}                              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu, float, multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{ccll}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Typ 2-Agent $\neq i$}                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Run}                                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Warten}                                               \\ \cline{3-4} 
    \multirow{3}{*}{Agent $i$ vom Typ 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Run}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\begin{cases} r_{1} & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit} \frac{1}{fr_{1}} \\0 & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit } 1-\frac{1}{fr_{1}} \end{cases}$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$r_{1}$}                                             \\ \cline{3-4} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Warten}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{0}}                                                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{(1-fr_{1})\tilde{R}}{1-f}$}} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                    \\ \cline{3-4} 
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Auszahlungsmatrix im ``Post-Deposit Game''}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which would give (may be you could cook up some white spacing to adjust the first row):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{Sc|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        &               &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Typ 2-Agent $\neq i$}                \\
        &               &   Run     &   Warten                                      \\
    \cline{3-4}
\multirow{4}{*}{Agent $i$ vom Typ 2}
        & \mc{Run}      &   \mc{$\displaystyle
                            \begin{cases}
                            r_{1} & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit } \frac{1}{fr_1} \\
                                0 & \text{mit Wahrscheinlichkeit } 1-\frac{1}{fr_1} \end{cases}$}
                                    &   \mc{$r_1$}                                  \\
    \cline{3-4}
        & \mc{Warten}   &   \mc{0}  &   \mc{$\dfrac{(1-fr_{1})\tilde{R}}{1-f}$}     \\
        \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Auszahlungsmatrix im ``Post-Deposit Game''}
\label{my-label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```